# Fixed thead only only when scrolling to top

Tags: css, html

I have a problem with a thead: I need to fix to top the thead when scrolling to top but at the same when I scroll horizontally the thead has to scroll horizontally  so I can't use the "position: fixed".
I'm using this cose but it does not work as I want.
Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    moveScroller();
  });

  function moveScroller() {
        var $anchor = $("#scroller-anchor");
        var $scroller = $('#scroller');

        var move = function() {
            var st = $(window).scrollTop();
            var ot = $anchor.offset().top;
            if(st > ot) {
                $scroller.css({
                    position: "fixed",
                    top: "0px"

                });
            } else {
                $scroller.css({
                    position: "relative",
                    top: ""
                });
            }
        };
        $(window).scroll(move);
        move();
    }
</script>

<div class="col-sm-12" id="scroller-anchor">    
<div class="table-responsive" id="cinquepuntodue">      
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed version" cellspacing="0" id = "cinquepuntodue_sopra">
    <thead  id="scroller" ></thead>
```

Comment: looks like you missed some parts of your code when you copy-pasted. please check again

Comment: yes, but the rest of the code is just the body of the table, do you need to see the css?

Comment: I mean your markup is incomplete sir. you're missing some closing div tags. So I'm assuming this code is not enough information